# Is there any standard to consume a webservice inside of native C++?

Tags: c++, web-services

I am looking for resources to show me how I can consume web services inside native C++ .  Are there any popular libraries I can use?

TIA

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what webservice architecture you are talking about... For XML-RPC  IBM [has a nice article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-xml-rpc/) showcasing XMLRPC++, for SOAP there is e.g. [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) or [WSO2 WSF/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166/c-web-service-framework/66239#66239), ...

Answer (score 1):

There are the [Axis2/C](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/c/) libraries, which, while C based rather than C++, are still easily employable - when I was working on Apache Tuscany, we used Axis2/C for our C++ Web Service bindings.

From the Axis2/C front page:
"Apache Axis2/C supports SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2, as well as REST style of Webservices. A single service could be exposed both as a SOAP style as well as a REST style service simultaneously. It also has built in MTOM support, that can be used to exchange binary data."